# What is the Sql Code to update my entire product catalog for a unique attribute?

Tags: magento-1.7

I uploaded product catalog and need a method via sql to change the status of an unique attribute that have installed. `{"use_external_image"  to yes}`. So all the images can show on the page.

Comment: Why not use the mass update method in the product grid to set the attribute for all products?

Answer (score 1):

If the value you are setting is a `varchar`, which it is if the value is the string *yes*, the query should be something like this

```
UPDATE 
 `catalog_product_entity_varchar` AS `attr_value`, 
 `eav_attribute` AS `attr_entity` 
SET 
 `attr_value`.`value` = 'yes' 
WHERE 
 `attr_value`.`attribute_id` = `attr_entity`.`attribute_id` 
 AND `attr_entity`.`attribute_code` = 'use_external_image'
```

A safer and cleaner way would be to use the Catalog Product Action model that can set an attribute value for an array of product IDs

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
   ->getCollection()
   ->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH);

Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_action')
    ->updateAttributes($collection->getAllIds(), array('use_external_image' => 'yes'), $storeId);
```